# Can't access virtualbox guest's (ubuntu server) localhost from host's (windows) browser

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox

I'm on Windows 10, and I have a virtualbox image running ubuntu server 18.04
I have configured NAT network (for internet connectivity) and a host-only adapter.
With this configuration I can ssh to my VM on `192.168.47.10`

And also if I run any docker container, I can reach it from the host, e.g: `docker run -d -p 8081:80 nginx`
can be reached from my host's browser on `192.168.47.10:8081`

The problem now is when I run a web application on `localhost:8080` of the guest, I can't reach it from the host's browser (192.168.47.10:8080 Unable to connect).

PS: My Windows Firewall is disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figure out that my webpack server is running on `localhost`, while in order to reach it from LAN, it should be running in `0.0.0.0`
So I just added `--host 0.0.0.0` to the command and the problem is solved.

Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35419631/7296938